# Can I use an RJ45 plug designed for UTP with STP wire?

Tags: rj45, stp

I have a non-standard application (model railroad) where I am planning to use CAT6 wiring between a custom made circuit board and a display panel.  The circuit board will have RJ45 ports (using breakout boards) while the opposite end will have multiple LED's and a momentary push button switch.  One single CAT6 cable gives me enough wires to run the LED's and switch, which is why I want to use it.  On the display panel end, I will be stripping back the wire and directly soldering it to the LED and push button leads.  On the circuit board end, I will be terminating the wire to an RJ45 plug.  I would note that I do not care between CAT 5 or 6 as I'm not using this for data transport.  This is also low voltage (12 volts and amps are in the few dozen milliamp range).

I currently have CAT6 STP cable that is 23AWG and solid core.  I like this because it's heavier gauge than CAT5 but more specifically because it's solid core.  Doesn't really matter to me for soldering, but honestly I've had very little luck stripping the insulation off of "regular" CAT5 cable (stranded/24 AWG).  Maybe it's just the CAT 5 cable I'm tryin with is too cheap, not sure.  Regardless, the only success I've had in stripping back insulation so far is with the heavier/solid CAT 6 STP.

My question here is, given my non-standard application, for the end of the cable that will terminate to an RJ45 jack do I really need to buy the fancy RJ45 connectors designed for STP?  They seem to be much more expensive and have extra crimping involved.  I am hoping that I can use any CAT6 connector (for UTP) that allows for 23AWG wire and specifically can handle the diameter of wire I have (~1.2mm).  Is that thinking correct?  I mean, the shielding for me is somewhat irrelevant and I will just strip the shielding back away far enough to clear the connector.

Comment: Sorry but can you explain what is it that you really want to know or ask? If you can strip the wires and crimp the connector, then you can use it if you think it is good enough for your purposes.

Comment: Probably, but the shields won't be connected. Could be uglier too, maybe.

Comment: Correct, Justme.  Sorry for using so many words to describe what is probably a very basic question but I really just want to know if using an RJ45 connector designed for UTP will work on shielded cable provided I don't care about the shielding and will simply peel it back out of the way, and provided I ensure that the connector will accept my wire diameter.  I am just wanting to use the shielded cable for it's other characteristics (larger gauge and solid core).

Comment: User253751, for my application I don't care about the shields, nor the visual appearance.  It will all be under a model train layout behind a display panel, so I'm going for function here, not form.  If I were putting RJ45 connectors on both ends, I would definitely just go w/ regular CAT5 or 6 cable.  But at the display panel side I will be soldering the individual wires to LED's and a pushbutton.  That requires that I can strip back the insulation on the wires and regular CAT5/6 cable I just haven't had success doing that.  Which is why I gravitated towards this shielded CAT6 cable.